# Android Application Designing in photoshop for all devices

Tags: android, user-interface, photoshop, screen-resolution

I am new to `android` application `UI` designs.Actually i want to know how to start application design for android in `Photoshop`?how to manage the `screen resolution`?.Please advice for design in `photoshop`.?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [this](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html) link. Where you can create icons for your android app.Just design your icons,and all image files in photoshop.And upload them in that website to get the correct resolution.You dont need to bother about screen sizes.Because when you get all the files with different resolution from the website, you only need to put them in res folder.Android will use the correct resoltion files according to screen size.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.i saw that link.Normally for android tablets in which resolution and dp i will start the designing and alignment work in photoshop?

Comment: it depends  but most of them are come under hdpi,before designing you should really check the resolution and density of the tablet.for more information you can follow the http://stefan222devel.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-screen-densities-sizes.html

Comment: Design in the resolution, 1920*1920 which is the maximum resolution so far.